# Is it possible to append a signature to a squashfs file, without causing problems with tools/mount?

Tags: squashfs, signature

I would like to authenticate a squashfs image, using a public-key signature. For an elegant implementation, it would be ideal if such a signature could simply be appended to the end of the squashfs image file.

Can squashfs tools, including kernel mount code, handle a squashfs image with some extra data appended to the end of the file, without any ill effect?

Answer (score 1):

As squashfs can reside on block devices, which have no relation in size to the filesystem size, apart from being at least as big, I would estimate that appending random data to a squashfs is unlikely to cause problems.

A quick browse through the kernel
[super.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/squashfs/super.c#L116)
driver function `squashfs_fill_super()` which seems to mount a squashfs,
does not show it being concerned with data beyond the end of the
`bytes_used` size given in the
[superblock](https://github.com/Othernet-Project/squashfs-tools/blob/master/README#L834),
which is at the start of the filesystem, and no error messages seem
relevant either.

Note, however, that a squashfs file is usually padded at the end to be a
multiple of 4Kibytes, so that it can be used with loopback block devices.
Make sure whatever you add is also a multiple of 4096 bytes.